# Postgres where query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

In our database we have a table `menus` having 515502 rows. It has a column `status` which is of type `smallint`.

Currently, a simple count query takes 700 ms for set of docs having value of `status` as `3`.

```
explain analyze select count(id) from menus where status = 2;
Aggregate  (cost=72973.71..72973.72 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=692.564..692.565 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on menus  (cost=2510.63..72638.80 rows=133962 width=4) (actual time=28.179..623.077 rows=135429 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (status = 2)
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 199654
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on menus_status  (cost=0.00..2477.14 rows=133962 width=0) (actual time=26.211..26.211 rows=135429 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (status = 2)
 Total runtime: 692.705 ms
(7 rows)
```

Some rows have column value of 1 for which the query runs very fast.

```
 explain analyze select count(id) from menus where status = 4;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=7198.73..7198.74 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=24.926..24.926 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on menus  (cost=40.53..7193.53 rows=2079 width=4) (actual time=1.461..23.418 rows=2220 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (status = 4)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on menus_status  (cost=0.00..40.02 rows=2079 width=0) (actual time=0.858..0.858 rows=2220 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (status = 4)
 Total runtime: 25.089 ms
(6 rows)
```

I observed that the most general `btree` index is the best indexing strategy for simple equality based queries. Both `gin` and `hash` were slower than `btree`.

Any tips for making `count` queries faster for any filter that is using an index?

I understand that this is a beginner level question, so apologies in advance for any kind of mistakes I might have made.

Comment: If you have one big table and the index usage is good, you can just try to optimize the process. I mean: will the status change often? Can you prepare a table with sums ready and mantain it with trigger or functions?

Comment: Changes to `status` happen very frequently and is only going to increase. Precomputing would only create lot of server issues, I think.

Comment: If the `status=4` -tuples are very hot (recently updated) the difference could be attributed to old row versions. Did you run `VACUUM` on the table? (the statistics look Ok, so autovacuum is probably enabled)

Comment: Is `id` a primary key for this table? Can you try to `count(*)` ?

Comment: Before running the queries I did run `VACUUM ANALYZE`. It took a lot of time. The first query after the `VACUUM` also took some time before stabilizing to give the above results.

Comment: OK, so you should be able to benefit from index-only scans (since 9.2) if the query and indexes are suitable, that's the main reason I wanted to know the version.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Yup. There is significant improvement. The time drops to around 225ms after I do `count(*)`.The reason seems to be the `index only scan` the db is making for the computation.

Comment: @user2512324 `count(status)` should work too. The reason `count(id)` doesn't is that PostgreSQL doesn't optimise `count(id)` to be equivalent to `count(1)` by proving that `id` is `NOT NULL`, so it thinks it has to fetch the `id` field, which isn't part of the index and thus can't be fetched using an index-only scan.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes. Now after doing `count(*)`, the db is indeed making `index only scan` making it significantly faster. Just asking, can I speed it up further?

Comment: If you need super-fast you may want to look at maintaining materialized views, either with triggers or periodically refreshed ones. Beware that trigger-maintained mat views tend to have implications for concurrency of insert/update/delete, and periodically updated ones will not be perfectly accurate.

Comment: @CraigRinger This looks like a super interesting feature. It could have been a more awesome had it allowed incremental concurrent indexing during update/insert/delete. But it still is pretty awesome.

Comment: @CraigRinger can you perhaps work all of these little knowledge gems into an answer that is more accessible to interested users than this discussion? You'll have my up-vote.

Comment: -ENOTIME right now, feel free to summarize/edit into an answer if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your table has more rows having status = 2 than ones having status = 4 , so, the total table access time is more for the second case. 
So, for status = 2 there are too many rows to consider, so the the Bitmap for the Bitmap Heap Scan goes to the "lossy" mode, and recheck is needed after the operation. So, there are two things to consider: either your result is too big (but you can't do anything with that without reorganizing your tables, say, with partitioning), or your '**work_mem**' param is too small to keep the intermittent result. Try to increase its value if you have possibility.